# 404 error when setting up views in django 1.11 polls app

Tags: python, django

I am using **MacOS HighSierra**, **django 1.11**, and **python 2.7.14**. Whenever I set up the views and run the server, polls/1 returns a 404 error. I am following the official django course. The page says this -

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/1
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$, [name='detail']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$, [name='results']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$, [name='vote']
^admin/
The current path, polls/1, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file.
Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: What is the error trace that you get back?

Comment: did you try `http://localhost:8000/polls/1/`? (append a slash(`/`))

Comment: show the content of your `urls.py` and `views.py`

Comment: did you have the poll object? (with pk 1)

Comment: I have tried polls/1/ Jerin Peter George. My urls.py in the mysite folder is this -

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: urls.py in polls folder - from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$,', views.detail, name="detail"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$,', views.results, name="results"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1/results
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$,', views.vote, name="vote"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1/results
]

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('This is the index page of the polls application')
def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("This is the detail view of the question %s" % question_id)
def results(request, question_id):
    response = "These are the results of the question %s"
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)
def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("Vote on question %s" % question_id)

Comment: that was views.py

Comment: @CoderMACi5 I don't see an answer to "seuling"s question: are you sure there are any polls instances in your database? Is there an instance with `pk=1`?

Comment: Is there a way to check if there are any polls instances in the database, @Ralf?

Comment: I am new to django, so I am not sure about these things

Comment: @CoderMACi5 Hm, it seems that `polls/1/` is looking for `Question` instances (apparently there is no `Poll` model). So you could try `Question.objects.all()` in the shell (`python manage.py shell`) and see if there is a question with `pk=1`.

Comment: There are two questions that show up when I type Question.objects.all() in the shell

Comment: I have the samie issue. How did you resolve this problem?